# Resuming an s3 bucket listing via boto

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

I'm iterating over 2 million objects thusly: -

```
conn = boto.connect_s3('xxx','xxx')
bucket = conn.lookup('bucket_name')

for key in bucket.list():
  somefunction(key.name)
```

Say it fails at the millionth object, how would I go about resuming this operation from that point?

Answer (score 9):

I figured it out by looking at the boto source.

```
def list(self, prefix='', delimiter='', marker='', headers=None):
```

Passing key.name to marker will allow you to resume your operation from that point.

Answer (score -1):

An example of resuming requests using the `marker` property.

This is also useful if you want to recurse through subtrees or have many millions of objects to crawl through and don't want them in a single list.

```
marker = None
while True:
    keys = bucket.get_all_keys(marker=marker)
    last_key = None

    for k in keys:
        # TODO Do something with your keys!
        last_key = k.name

    if not keys.is_truncated:
        break

    marker = last_key
```